# Why does RegEx output escaped text instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension which adds a `<span> ... </span>` around every string that matches a certain regular expression. The RegEx match works perfectly, but I cannot seem to find a way to correctly add the `span` tag around the text.

My code thus far is:

```
// main.js
var regex_pattern = new RegEx('(apple)', 'g'); // Let's pretend I want to match every instance of 'apple'
var textNodes = getTextNodes(); // A function that returns a list of every text node from the DOM
for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++) {
    if (textNodes[i].nodeValue.match(regex_pattern)) {
        textNodes[i].nodeValue = textNodes[i].nodeValue.replace(regex_pattern, "<span class='highlight'>$&</span>");
    }
}
```

This will correctly identify every match of my RegEx pattern (in this case 'apple') and output `<span class="highlight">apple</span>`. The only problem is that this is not treated as HTML by Chrome, it's treated as text - so instead of seeing the world 'apple' styled according to the `highlight` class, one would see the literal output: `<span class="highlight">apple<span>`

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it so that the style is correctly applied? Realizing that this was less than desirable, I tried using the `insertBefore()` method to wrap the matched text in a span, but this didn't do anything, it would either error or fail to add the `span` node, depending on how I tweaked the code. Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: You need to use `createElement` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `nodeValue` to replace a text node with arbitrary HTML.

You must do it manually:

```js
function replaceNodeWithHTML(node, html) {
  var parent = node.parentNode;
  if(!parent) return;
  var next = node.nextSibling;
  var parser = document.createElement('div');
  parser.innerHTML = html;
  while(parser.firstChild)
    parent.insertBefore(parser.firstChild, next);
  parent.removeChild(node);
}
var regex_pattern = /(apple)/g;
var textNodes = [document.querySelector('div').firstChild];
for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++)
  if (textNodes[i].nodeValue.match(regex_pattern))
    replaceNodeWithHTML(
      textNodes[i], 
      textNodes[i].nodeValue.replace(regex_pattern, "<span class='highlight'>$&</span>")
    );
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>I have an (apple). You have an (apple) too.</div>
```

It would be easier if nodes had [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method, but only elements do.

Answer (score 0):

Set [.innerHTML](https://devdocs.io/dom/element/innerhtml) on the element. Setting textNode.nodeValue value direcly sets the text.